# Delete occurrence of sublist in LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to solve a problem that should delete occurrence of sublist in a given list.
For example:
Input:
List: a b c d d b c a e a e
Sublist:  b c
Output: a d d a e a e
Can anyone give me some advice or some tips how can i do it. My code gives null pointer exception.

```
public static void deleteSublist(DLL<Character> lista1, DLL<Character> lista2){
    DLL<Character> finalList = new DLL<Character>();
    DLLNode<Character> node1 = lista1.getFirst();
    DLLNode<Character> temp = lista1.getFirst();
    DLLNode<Character> node2 = lista2.getFirst();
    int len1 = lista1.length();
    int len2 = lista2.length();
    int count = 0;
    boolean check = false;

    while(node1 != null){
        check = false;
        node2 = lista2.getFirst();
        temp = node1;

        while(temp != null){
            if(!temp.element.equals(node2.element)){
                check = true; // no sublist
                break;
            }
            temp = temp.succ;
            node2 = node2.succ;
        }

        if(!check){             //we have sublist
                //Here I should delete sublist
        }

        node1 = node1.succ;
    }


}
```

Comment: Where is the NPE being thrown?

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic it's thrown in the line  temp=temp.succ

Comment: *Fascinating...* That seems unlikely, since that means `temp` would be `null`, which means `temp != null` would yield `false` and `temp.element` would have caused a NPE.

Comment: BTW: the [KMP algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) would be a efficient way of finding the sublists.

Comment: @fabian i deleted everything inside the while(temp != null) except temp=temp.succ and it still gives NPE. It's so annoying

Comment: Did you compile the new code?